# How to parse HZK16 in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript

do you know is there a open-source hkz16 ActionScript parser?

Answer (score 0):

what is hzk16 (or hkz16)? there's not even a wiki-article about it. and google results are not really helpful either. (from that I also guess, there is no such thing)

Answer (score 0):

hzk16 is an 16x16 pixel matrix font lib for chinese characters. It was widely used in old DOS system. Though there isn't an open-source AS parser implementation as far as I know. There are quite a few java parsers, which you can port to AS.